# Using Slim Framework with Swagger PHP

Tags: swagger, slim, swagger-ui

I've been looking for a work around sample code for Slim PHP and Swagger PHP, but cannot get it implemented, any help please, I'm tired.

Comment: I tried using Slagger, https://github.com/schirinos/slagger but i cannot just integrate it, is there any easier one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like slagger hasn't been upgraded to Slim v3 yet. I tried it and it wouldn't work.
However, I found a suggestion which worked for me:
- install https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php
- add a new route in slim:

```
$app->get('/v1/doco', function($request, $response, $args) {
    $swagger = \Swagger\scan([/path/to/your/routes/directory]);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $swagger;
});
```

Then navigate to /api/v1/doco and you should see the swagger JSON.

Next up is to provide the Swagger UI, which I'm still working on, hoping the following will work (will update if I get it working)!!!
http://blog.nbostech.com/2016/01/integrating-swagger-ui-for-php-application/